# Where do I extract tar archive in linux?

Tags: apt, software-installation, tar

I use Ubuntu's derivative Xubuntu. Sometimes a software I would like to install is not available in the **apt** repository and can be downloaded in form of compressed **tar** archive. What would be the proper way to extract the archive and install the software in the system so it available from the drop down menu on the top left corner and the terminal? Do I extract it to the `/sub/bin` directory and add the `.desktop` extension to the `.bashrc` file as a path? How do I make it available from the `xfce` drop down menu on the top left of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` so that it shows up in the menu.

You can put the binary executable wherever you want to, it would work as long as the .desktop file points to it. For example, you can put it in
`~/.local/bin`, so that you can call it from the terminal.